# Выведение столбца по условиям when then

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql, pandas

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите, пожалуйста, как написать эти условия на python и вывести в отдельном столбце с сохранением текущих??
Нужно вывести столбец с условием

```
when total_sessions = 1 then 1.0
when total_sessions = 2 then 0.5
when visitNumber = 1 then 0.4
when visitNumber= total_sessions then 0.4
else 0.2 / (total_sessions - 2)
end as forty_twenty_forty_points`
```

Comment: А не проще посчитать их прямо в запросе?

Comment: почему исходные данные скриншотом? отредактируйте вопрос, чтобы данные были в текстовом виде

Comment: эта переменная выведена объединением 2 разных запросов